# Calling a function in another function behaviour

Tags: python, function, python-3.4

I'm trying to understand this behaviour, a simple test here

```
def hello():
    a="Hi"
    return a

def choice():
    x=int(input("test: "))
    if x == 1:
        hello()

choice()
```

I expect that if I input `1` it will print `Hi`, but here is the output;

```
>>> 
test: 1
>>>
```

Nothing. Even there is no error, program just ending. I'm wondering why this Python behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Because you never tell it to print anywhere. Try this instead if you expect that output:

```
...
if x == 1:
    print(hello())
...
```

Comment: I'm returning a value

Comment: @qwerty- you sure are, but you're not telling the program to do anything with that value. This code tells the program to calculate the value of `hello()` (which is `'Hi'`), then print it. Your code tells the program to calculate the value of `hello()` (which is still `'Hi'`), then do nothing with it at all.